# Is it possible to dynamically replace a tag by a Svelte Component?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

So I created a blog, which dynamically fetches and parses `.md` markdown files and renders the content.
Now I want to pep up everything a little bit. HTML-Tags will are parsed as such, so

```
<div>foo</div>
```

will be rendered as

```html
<div>
  foo
</div>
```

But unfornately, but also logically, a custom Svelte-Component e.g. `<Foo />` will just render as

```html
<Foo></Foo>
```

and not the component itself.
So is there a way, that I can live replace the tags by their corresponding component?

Comment: You may want to look at MDsveX https://github.com/pngwn/MDsveX

Comment: Thank you very much! I searched for hours but didn't looked for other markdown parser as I had a working one. MDsveX solved this task!